# Why is SSH, Active: inactive (dead)?

Tags: ssh, services

I am trying to run sshd. When I check its status, I am presented with this:

```
root@mini2-game1-30001:~# /etc/init.d/ssh status
* ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
root@mini2-game1-30001:~# /etc/init.d/ssh start
Starting ssh (via systemctl): ssh.service.
root@mini2-game1-30001:~#  update-rc.d ssh defaults 3
root@mini2-game1-30001:~#  update-rc.d ssh enable
root@mini2-game1-30001:~# reboot
root@mini2-game1-30001:~# /etc/init.d/ssh status 
* ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

What could be the cause of this and how can I fix it.

Comment: Check the logs?

Comment: root@mini2-game1-30001:/var/log# cat auth.log | grep ssh
Dec  5 15:14:14 mini2-game1-30001 sshd[20959]: rexec line 14: Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
Dec  5 15:14:14 mini2-game1-30001 sshd[20959]: rexec line 15: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits
Dec  5 15:14:14 mini2-game1-30001 sshd[20959]: rexec line 22: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Dec  5 15:14:14 mini2-game1-30001 sshd[20959]: rexec line 29: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication

Comment: root@mini2-game1-30001:/var/log# cat syslog | grep ssh
Dec  5 15:14:20 mini2-game1-30001 systemd[20976]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Dec  5 15:43:48 mini2-game1-30001 sshd[18768]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 14: Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
Dec  5 15:43:48 mini2-game1-30001 sshd[18768]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 15: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits
Dec  5 15:43:48 mini2-game1-30001 sshd[18768]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 16: Deprecated option UsePrivilegeSeparation

Comment: Deprecated option doesn't make the ssh dead. Check the answer, it is what can be said from here.

Comment: what happen when you use proper way of starting a service with systemd `systemctl start sshd` ? and what happen when checking status `systemctl status sshd`

Answer (score 2):

I experimented and found that if I block the port with my firewall it shuts down after a period of time. If the port is blocked from boot, it may never come up. So it could be that the port is being blocked. Also, it could be a misconfigured sshd_config. That is causing the ssh service to shut down.

You can test the configuration:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -t
or
sshd -t
```

If there is an error it will tell you, if not nothing is displayed.

Comment: root@mini2-game1-30001:/var/log# sshd -t
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 10: Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 11: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 18: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 25: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication

Comment: Deprecated options will not cause this, I will keep thinking...

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#SSH_agent